# C++ How to set new MachineGuid

Tags: c++, registry

I'm using this code to change new (rewrite) MachineGuid in registry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography

But I can't change it. I can change HwProfileGuid in

> SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware
> Profiles\0001

but not this one.

```
HKEY hKey_;
LPCTSTR sk_MachineGuid = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography");
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk_MachineGuid, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey_);
LPCTSTR val_MachineGuid = TEXT("MachineGuid");
SetStringValue(hKey_, val_MachineGuid, w_MachineGuid /* generated MachineGuid */);
RegCloseKey(hKey_);
```

Anyone who can help me please?

Comment: You should be testing the [return codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa) for those Windows API functions.  Each one of those functions returns a return code.  The link states: *If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h. You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error.*

Comment: i did this and i got ERROR_SUCCESS. So there wasnt any problem with setting new value.. But the value was not replaced.. So weird @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @0xM3G4 You don't say whether that's a 32-bit compile by any chance, and you don't show `val_MachineGuid`, or `SetStringValue`.